# IndexError: list index out of range: sys.argv[1] out of range

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to run the following code but keep running into an error,
 "IndexError: list index out of range"

I understand that this is todo with the sys.argv[1]; I have a basic idea that this function is call the first line of my project from the command line - when I try to run the project from CMD I run into the same error.

The code:

```
import cv2
import sys

cascadePath = sys.argv[1]
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath)

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Niku/PycharmProjects/FaceDetection/FaceDetection.py", line 4, in <module>
    cascadePath = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any insight or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you running the script ?

Comment: How did you exactly invoke your program?

Comment: Also, you can inspect what is in the sys.argv list by temporarily replacing `cascadePath = sys.argv[1]` with `print(sys.argv)`

Comment: @Sushanth  - I'm using PyCharm as an IDE; I've tried running it from my IDE, also tried running from terminal in IDE and tried booting from CMD.

Comment: @Ronald I'm using PyCharm as an IDE; I've tried running it from my IDE, also tried running from terminal in IDE and tried booting from CMD.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse (sometimes) as an IDE. I have never worked with PyCharm, but in Eclipse there is a special window where you must/can set your command line options. Perhaps there is something similar in PyCharm?

Comment: Look here: https://www.askpython.com/python/python-command-line-arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.argv[1]` This code expects first command line argument. If that's missing then you will encounter this error.
Example:

some_script.py

```
import sys
sys.argv[1]
```

If you dont provide `myfirst_agr`(as shown below) then it will throw Index error what you are seeing.

```
some_script.py myfirst_agr
```

More examples are [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-sys-argv-in-python/amp/)

Comment: Thanks for the simple breakdown and referral to the documentation, very helpful! When running the code from CMD with the myfirst_arg, I ran into another error:

`faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: 
(-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale`


Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: @Karanvir.S.G, that's totally different issue. You can raise another question for that.

Comment: @Karanvir.S.G, If it was helpful answer can you please accept this answer ?